# How to add Q&A captcha into Redsilver3 style in phpbb

Tags: phpbb

I am maintaining a phpbb forum. The style used in the forum is Redsilver3, which supports phpbb version 3.0.4. I have updated the forum version to 3.0.11 so that I can use Q&A captcha to prevent spam. The Q&A captcha was successfully activated on the forum, but it is not displaying the captcha on Redsilver3. I tried updating the Redsilver3 file by adding code

```
"<!-- IF CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE and S_CONFIRM_CODE -->
        <!-- INCLUDE {CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE} -->
        <!-- ENDIF -->"
```

in the posting_body.html  in the Redsilver3 template folder and purged the cache. But still it is not displaying the captcha. I have also tried by replacing all the files with latest version of Redsilver3 but the captcha was not showing. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the captcha_qa.html and captcha_default.html from the latest version of subsilver2 and added the code

to the ucp_register.html file and the captcha was working perfectly.

Earlier I copied captcha_qa.html and captcha_default.html from the latest version of Redsilver3 and have added the code to posting_body.html, so it was not working.

I got the idea after asking the same question on phpbb forum. Here is the link https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=2166883&p=13210671#p13210671